# How to capture image using IP connected camera in asp dot net web API and ReactJS as client

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, rtsp

I am working on a project where I need to capture images using an IP connected camera.
And then display it on the client-side.

I am using .net core Web API on the server-side and React Js on the client-side.

I found RTSP is the way but I don't found any good reference for that.

PS:
I like to capture images/snapshots from that video source also.

Answer (score 0):

It usually have nothing to do with `react.js` itself.

If your camera support `RTSP` then you need some `JavaScript` code to capture video from. Additionally, you need a RTSP connection url like this:

```
rtsp://username:password@IP Address/h265/ch1/main/av_stream
```

So, you better to find a `js` library for it, like `node-rtsp-stream`

**Update**
AFAIK to use libraries such as `node-rtsp-stream`, you are not forced to use them via `node`. They are just js files which can be imported to your `react.js` front-end.

Comment: I am not planning to create a new node server for that. As I already have dot net as server side.